# Python Script throws Memory Error

Tags: python, list, memory, directory

I made a script that will map me a directory and give me stats about it ...
Here's the script:

```
import os 
import hashlib
import platform
import sys
import argparse
import HTML

class Map(object):

    def __init__(self,param):
        self.param_list = param
        self.slash = self.slash_by_os()
        self.result_list = []
        self.os = ""


    def calc_md5(self,file_path):
        with open(file_path) as file_to_check:
            data = file_to_check.read()    
            md5_returned = hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()

        return md5_returned

    def slash_by_os(self):
        general_id = platform.system()
        actual_os = ""

        if general_id == "Darwin" or general_id == "darwin":
            actual_os = "UNIX"
        elif general_id == "Linux" or general_id == "linux":
            actual_os = "UNIX"
        elif general_id  == "SunOS":
            actual_os = "UNIX"
        elif general_id == "Windows" or general_id == "windows":
            actual_os = "WIN"
        else:
            actual_os = general_id

        if actual_os == "UNIX":
            return '/'
        elif actual_os == "WIN":
            return '\\'
        else:
            return '/'

        self.os = actual_os

    def what_to_do(self,new_dir):
        act = []
        act.append(new_dir[:-1])
        for param in self.param_list:
            if param == "md5":
                x = self.calc_md5(new_dir[:-1])
                act.append(x)
            elif param == "size":
                x = os.stat(new_dir[:-1]).st_size
                act.append(x)
            elif param == "access":
                x = os.stat(new_dir[:-1]).st_atime
                act.append(x)
            elif param == "modify":
                x = os.stat(new_dir[:-1]).st_mtime
                act.append(x)
            elif param == "creation":
                    x = os.stat(new_dir[:-1]).st_ctime
                    act.append(x)   

        return act

    def list_of_files(self ,dir_name ,traversed = [], results = []): 

        dirs = os.listdir(dir_name)
        if dirs:
            for f in dirs:
                new_dir = dir_name + f + self.slash
                if os.path.isdir(new_dir) and new_dir not in traversed:
                    traversed.append(new_dir)
                    self.list_of_files(new_dir, traversed, results)
                else:
                    act = self.what_to_do(new_dir)
                    results.append(act)
        self.result_list = results  
        return results


def parse_args():
    desc = "Welcom To dirmap.py 1.0"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=desc)
    parser.add_argument('-p','--path', help='Path To Original Directory', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-md','--md5', action = 'store_true',help='Show md5 hash of file', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-s','--size', action = 'store_true', help='Show size of file', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-a','--access', action = 'store_true',  help='Show access time of file', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-m','--modify', action = 'store_true', help='Show modification time of file', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-c','--creation', action = 'store_true', help='Show creation of file', required=False)

    args = vars(parser.parse_args())

    params = []
    for key,value in args.iteritems():
        if value == True:
            params.append(key)

    return args,params



def main():
    args , params = parse_args() 
    dir_path = args['path']
    map = Map(params)
    dir_list = map.list_of_files(dir_path)

    params.insert(0,"path")


    htmlcode_dir = HTML.table(dir_list,header_row=params)
    print htmlcode_dir

main()
```

When I try to run it on medium to large directories it throws me a MemoryError exception...
as you can see here:

```
python(2374) malloc: *** mmap(size=140514183884800) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "dirmap.py", line 132, in <module>
     main()
   File "dirmap.py", line 124, in main
     dir_list = map.list_of_files(dir_path)
   File "dirmap.py", line 86, in list_of_files
     self.list_of_files(new_dir, traversed, results)
   File "dirmap.py", line 86, in list_of_files
     self.list_of_files(new_dir, traversed, results)
   File "dirmap.py", line 86, in list_of_files
     self.list_of_files(new_dir, traversed, results)
   File "dirmap.py", line 88, in list_of_files
     act = self.what_to_do(new_dir)
   File "dirmap.py", line 60, in what_to_do
     x = self.calc_md5(new_dir[:-1])
   File "dirmap.py", line 25, in calc_md5
     data = file_to_check.read()
MemoryError
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you paste the traceback? I'd also suggest not [using lists as the default values for keyword arguments](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/category/python-gotchas/) (as you've done in `list_of_files`).

Comment: I don't really know what is traceback..  But what should I use if not lists?

Comment: @beetea: The traceback was there, just not formatted very well. I've fixed it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading a large file into memory in one go. Don't do that, read it in chunks and update the hash as you go along:

```
def calc_md5(self,file_path):
    hash = hashlib.md5()
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_to_check:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: file_to_check.read(4096), ''):    
            hash.update(chunk)

    return hash.hexdigest()
```

This opens the file in *binary* mode, avoiding interpreting different line-ending conventions (which would alter the hash).

The above code uses the two-argument form of the [`iter()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter), where the second argument is the sentinel value; iteration stops when the first argument, a callable, returns the second argument. Python file objects return an empty string when EOF is reached.

Comment: So which approach should I go with? Chunks or lines?

Comment: @FernandoRetimo: After having thought a bit more about it, go with chunks and binary reading. Opening a file in text mode can alter how line endings are interpreted, for example.

Comment: I'll look into it try it, and tell it the results.

Comment: Works Perfectly my friend, much appreciated!

Comment: My friend... another issue came by. On Mac OSX (assuming all linux), i run this on the root directory and it throws IEOrror Errno 102 operation not supported on socket... it failed while tryoing to open file with 'rb' ... Any suggestions?

Comment: Not certain what you mean there. Are you certain you are only opening files and not sockets?

Comment: well I need to scan through every file , it theres a socket there and os.listdir() validated it as a file, i think it has to be on my list...

Comment: No, `os.listdir()` lists *names*, it doesn't limit this to just files. I **think** the `os.path.isfile()` test can be used to filter out sockets.

Comment: can you please show me how you would integrate it to my script?

Comment: look to my question again on top i edited it so you could see the traceback i get ...

Comment: @FernandoRetimo: how about you make that a new question instead? That'll make it easier for others to reuse the answers to that question.

Comment: @FernandoRetimo: You could also just use `try:`, `except IOError: return` to skip invalid files.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into a large file and fail to read it all into memory in calc_md5(). Use a buffered approach